# Why $form->isValid() returns false when testing although it's true in production?

Tags: symfony, testing, symfony-3.4

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and I'm writing tests for my actions

And as mentioned in the title `$form->isValid()` returns `false` although it works fine when I test the form in production.

In my tests I try to simulate POST request like so:

```
$crawler = $this->_client->request('GET', $this->_router->generate('product_new'));
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
$values = $form->getPhpValues();
$values['product']['code'] = 'PRD';
$values['product']['name'] = 'TEST PRODUCT';
$values['product']['price'] = 550;
$this->_client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values, $form->getPhpFiles());
$response = $this->_client->getResponse();
// the response should return 302 because I'm doing redirection after submitting the form
// so this one should return true
$this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_FOUND, $response->getStatusCode());
```

And this is the action in `ProductController` class:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="product_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function createAction(){
      $product = new Product();
      $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

      $form->handleRequest($request);
      // when I remove $form->isValid() the test works fine
      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $em->persist($product);
          $em->flush();
          return $this->redirectToRoute('product_show', array('code' => $product->getCode()));
      }

      return $this->render('@Commerce/product/new.html.twig', array(
        'product' => $product,
        'form' => $form->createView()
      )); 
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with submitting an empty field that is returned by `getPhpValues()`? Have you tried using the crawler to fetch the button and then using `$client->submit($form);` as described in the docs section first? See: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing.html#forms

Comment: @dbrumann the problem with this methode is that I get "Unreachable fields" exception for colleciton fields !

Comment: Ah, if you actually use this for form collections, then it makes sense to have it. Do you see any errors in your test.log? I would also recommend enabling the profiler for the test environment (if not done so already) and then extracting the profiler url from the response header in your test to have a closer look at the form validation to see why it is not considered valid.

Comment: @dbrumann actually I get not error in the `test.log` file ! also how can I enable profiler and extract the profiler url from the response ? I have no idea about this one :p

Comment: @dbrumann I found how to enable profiler and get its url, thanks for the hint I will check why the validation is not working

Comment: @dbrumann OMG I can't belive it I found the problem is in the name of a field I set `adresse` instead of `àddress` !! now it's working thanks again for the profiler hint :)